Accessing Ollama running locally from Minikube on MacOS
I'm working on a microservice project thats needs to connect to Ollama.
I use:

Minikube for local kubernetes
Ollama for llm server

As of today, you cannot use Ollama as docker image with Apple GPU: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/apple-silicon-gpus-docker-and-ollama-pick-two/
And by default when you try to connect your services within minikube to local ollama through host.minikube.internal:11434 it doesn't work.
I've try to:

Add firewall rules to accept outside connection to ollama app


Ollama binds 127.0.0.1 port 11434 by default.
https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/faq.md#setting-environment-variables-on-mac
For Ollama accepting minikube request you need to start it on 0.0.0.0
For this you need to run in a terminal:
launchctl setenv OLLAMA_HOST 0.0.0.0:11434

And then restart your Ollama App.
Don't forget to check your firewall rules for Ollama App.
then from your microservice running in minikube  you can reference your local Ollama server with http://host.minikube.internal:11434
